# validation filter for inherited property mvc model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, inheritance, filter

I have a model imported from entity data framework
    public class person
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }

and a viewmodel inherited from person

```
public class personviewmodel:person
{
    public int Applied {get; set;}
}
```

I use personviewmodel as the model in my view. I would like to add error validation (data annotation) to 'Name' property without modifying the generated 'person' class. Can you please help get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement validation as follows. But thing here you are not inheriting Person using person's object as is. Hope this will help you.

```
 public class Person 
 { 
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message")]
   public string Name {get; set;} 
 }

 public class personviewmodel
 {
   public int Applied {get; set;}
   public Person Person {get; set;}
 }
```

or

```
 public class Person 
 { 
   public string Name {get; set;} 
 }

 public class Personviewmodel : Person
 {
   public int Applied {get; set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
   public new string Name {get; set;} 
 }
```

or

```
 public class Person 
 { 
   public virtual string Name {get; set;} 
 }

 public class Personviewmodel : Person
 {
   public int Applied {get; set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
   public override string Name {get; set;} 
 }
```

Comment: In that case you need to mark Name property virtual in Person class and then you can use case use it. See the update in answer.